# Busqueda luego de LostFocus,encuentra pero no me trae los datos

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, buscador

Buenas noches amigos estoy agilizando uno de mis procesos en un sistema, ya que tengo un formulario(`frmventas`) que posee varios `TextBox` como: `txtidarticulo`, `txtnombre`, `txtcantidad`, `txtprecio` entre otros. en `txtidarticulo` existe  un botón al lado `btnbuscar`, este llama un formulario(`frmMostrar_articulos`) con una `grid` un `combobox` y un `textbox` donde el `combobox` tiene dos opciones de búsqueda: `código`, `nombre` y el `botón` solo filtra lo que esta seleccionado con lo que dice en el `textbox`, lo muestra en la `grid` y al darle `dobleclic` a un dato el carga el resto de la informacion a las caja de texto mencionadas antes(`frmventas`). como ven para la practica una persona que vaya a buscar 10 productos es muy largo el proceso. Estoy  tratando de hacer lo mismo en el evento `LostFocus` del `txtidarticulo` los encuentra pero no coloca la información en las demás cajas de texto de su mismo formulario. esto es lo que tengo:
la primera capa:

```
public DataTable MostrarArticulo_Venta_codigo(String TextoBuscar)
{
    DataTable DtResultado = new DataTable("articulos");
    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();
    try
    {
        SqlCon.ConnectionString = Conexion.Cn;
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
        SqlCmd.CommandText = "spbuscararticulo_venta_codigo";
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter ParTextoBuscar = new SqlParameter();
        ParTextoBuscar.ParameterName = "@textobuscar";
        ParTextoBuscar.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        ParTextoBuscar.Size = 50;
        ParTextoBuscar.Value = TextoBuscar;
        SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(ParTextoBuscar);

        SqlDataAdapter SqlDat = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
        SqlDat.Fill(DtResultado);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DtResultado = null;
    }
    return DtResultado;

}
```

segunda capa:

```
public static DataTable MostrarArticulo_Venta_Codigo(string textobuscar)
{
    DVenta Obj = new DVenta();
    return Obj.MostrarArticulo_Venta_codigo(textobuscar);
}
```

y el evento de la tercera capa ese `cbbuscar` que se ve fue para jugar sucio le coloque texto:"código" y `visible`= `false` y gracias a eso esta buscando pero se que no es la practica correcta:

```
private void txtIdarticulo_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbBuscar.Text.Equals("Codigo"))
    {
        this.MostrarArticulo_Venta_Codigo();
    }

    FrmVenta form = FrmVenta.GetInstancia();
        string par1, par2;
        decimal par3, par4;
        int par5;
        DateTime par6;
        par1 = Convert.ToString(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["iddetalle_ingreso"].Value);
        par2 = Convert.ToString(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["nombre"].Value);
        par3 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["precio_compra"].Value);
        par4 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["precio_venta"].Value);
        par5 = Convert.ToInt32(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["stock_actual"].Value);
        par6 = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["fecha_vencimiento"].Value);
        form.setArticulo(par1, par2, par3, par4, par5, par6);

}




 public void setArticulo (string iddetalle_ingreso,string nombre,
        decimal precio_compra,decimal precio_venta,int stock,
        DateTime fecha_vencimiento)
    {
        this.txtIdarticulo.Text = iddetalle_ingreso;
        this.txtArticulo.Text = nombre;
        this.txtPrecio_Compra.Text = Convert.ToString(precio_compra);
        this.txtPrecio_Venta.Text = Convert.ToString(precio_venta);
        this.txtStock_Actual.Text = Convert.ToString(stock);
        this.dtFecha_Vencimiento.Value = fecha_vencimiento;
    }
```

luego del breakpoint:

[[image: luego de hacer <code>breakpoint</code>]

pero el `DataTable` es como si no estuviese activo, otra cosa 
cambie el evento a `TextChanged` por que en `lostFocus` ni siquiera se activaba pero tiene que solucionarse una cosa a la vez

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código del método `setArticulo`? sin haber visto el código aún, creo que no estás colocando la información en los campos de este formulario...

Comment: ya agregue el `setArticulo` a la pregunta amigo @Mauricio

Comment: Gilberto, revisa tu variable de tipo `DataTable` _que creo en este caso sería_ ¿`dataListado`? para comprobar si el DataTable efectivamente tiene datos, te sugiero colocar un punto de interrupción en esta línea: `par1 = Convert.ToString(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["iddetalle_ingreso"].Value);` y verifica el contenido del DataTable.

Comment: ok amigo intentare con el punto de interrupción y te aviso, muchas gracias

Comment: @Mauricio ya edite la pregunta luego del `breakpoint`

Comment: Gilberto, el datatable está vacío y/o no tiene datos. Prueba lo siguiente, antes del punto de interrupción coloca: `if (this.dataListado.Rows.Count > 0)`. Colocaré una respuesta detallando un poco mas lo que deberías hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes validar que tu DataTable contenga datos.

Modifica tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
private void txtIdarticulo_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbBuscar.Text.Equals("Codigo"))
    {
        this.MostrarArticulo_Venta_Codigo();
    }

    FrmVenta form = FrmVenta.GetInstancia();
    string par1, par2;
    decimal par3, par4;
    int par5;
    DateTime par6;

    // Comprueba primero que tu datatable tenga datos:
    if (dataListado != null && dataListado.Rows.Count > 0) 
    {
        par1 = Convert.ToString(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["iddetalle_ingreso"].Value);
        par2 = Convert.ToString(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["nombre"].Value);
        par3 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["precio_compra"].Value);
        par4 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["precio_venta"].Value);
        par5 = Convert.ToInt32(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["stock_actual"].Value);
        par6 = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["fecha_vencimiento"].Value);
        form.setArticulo(par1, par2, par3, par4, par5, par6);
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No hay datos.");
    }   
}
```

Iré editando esta respuesta para intentar ayudarte.

Comment: Perfecto este fin de semana me pongo en esto muchas gracias